# Error when building relationship between to tables with multiple primary keys in SQLAlchemy with MS SQL EXPRESS

Tags: sql, orm, sqlalchemy

I am trying to build the relationship between the tables ***recipes*** and ***placement_groups*** with SQLAlchemy.

```
class Recipe(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'recipes'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    pro_id = Column(String(13), ForeignKey('products.id'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    # one-to-many relationship (Product-Recipe)
    product = relationship('Product', back_populates='recipes')

    # one-to-many relationship (Recipe-PlacementGroup)
    placement_groups = relationship('PlacementGroup', back_populates='recipe')

    def __init__(self, pro_id, name, placement_groups):
        self.pro_id = pro_id
        self.name = name
        self.placement_groups = placement_groups


class PlacementGroup(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'placement_groups'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    step = Column(Integer, autoincrement=False)

    # one-to-many relationship (Recipe-PlacementGroup)
    recipe_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('recipes.id'))
    pro_id = Column(String(13), ForeignKey('recipes.pro_id'))
    ForeignKeyConstraint(('recipe_id', 'pro_id'), ['recipes.id', 'recipes.pro_id'])
    recipe = relationship('Recipe', back_populates='placement_groups', foreign_keys=[recipe_id, pro_id])

    # one-to-many relationship (PlacementGroup-PartPlacement)
    part_placements = relationship('PartPlacement', back_populates='placement_group')

    def __init__(self, part_placements, step):
        self.part_placements = part_placements
        self.step = step
```

The SQL output is

```
CREATE TABLE recipes (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    pro_id VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id, pro_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(pro_id) REFERENCES products (id)
)

CREATE TABLE placement_groups (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), 
    step INTEGER NULL, 
    recipe_id INTEGER NULL, 
    pro_id VARCHAR(13) NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(recipe_id) REFERENCES recipes (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(pro_id) REFERENCES recipes (pro_id)
)
```

The resulting error is

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'recipes' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__placement__recip__2057CCD0'. (1776) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors. (1750)")
[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE placement_groups (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), 
    step INTEGER NULL, 
    recipe_id INTEGER NULL, 
    pro_id VARCHAR(13) NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(recipe_id) REFERENCES recipes (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(pro_id) REFERENCES recipes (pro_id)
)
```

I think that might be about connecting the ForeignKey in PlacementGroup properly to the multi-primary-key in Recipe. But I don't know how to do that. I did not find any similar problem in my research regarding this issue.

Can anybody tell me how to properly set up this relationship?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61525160/2144390) helpful.

Comment: Thank you @GordThompson, I implemented the solution you suggested and it worked for me! First I continued to have issues, but I had to delete the "ForeignKey('recipes.id')" inside the column definition of my Child class. Thank you a lot!